# System.NullReferenceException in QTP 11.5 during batch testing

Tags: testing, qtp

In QTP 11.5, the batch test tool isn't working properly.

I get this error System.NullReferenceException .

[image: Batch Test Error]

Can someone please tell me how to solve it? Or give an alternative tool for batch test?

Comment: Does it tell you _what_ is throwing the null reference exception?  That generally means that the test is trying to access something that is now out-of-scope or hasn't been initialized.

Comment: I recommend against using the batch tool just due to errors like the ones you receive. In other words: That one appears to be buggy, or at least imperfect if you test uses certain features.

Comment: What is throwing? I dont know. There is stack trace in the image if that leads you to anywhere.

@TheBlastOne - I have partially automated QTP to make the batch test easier. The error remains but batch test can be performed.